# Effect of "D" grade in PhD-level course on job prospects

Tags: phd, grades

I am a PhD student and have a *D* in one of my exams due to some family issues. I also have a *B* in 3 subjects and *A* in one. I am worried about my future. will the *D* have an impact on my job prospects even if I maintain my GPA above 3.3?

Comment: This is difficult to answer without more context.  In some US math grad programs, the typical grade is A, a B is worrisome, and lower than a B is a very serious problem.  However, that may vary between programs.  To a first approximation, nobody will care much about your grades if you write a good thesis.  However, if your grades aren't good, then the department may kick you out.  You definitely need to talk with your advisor about his/her view of this situation.

Comment: In most US programs, a "D" can be cause for academic probation, or worse. It can also have an impact with employers if they impose GPA cutoffs—and many bigger R&D units are affiliated with companies that do exactly that. As Anonymous Mathematician suggests, you should talk with your advisor, as well as the graduate officer of your department for guidance.

Comment: yeah my graduate committee toldme to be on probation until i gets 2B and one A in next 9 credit hours. thats not an issue as i am confident to fulfill this requirement. but my biggest worry is in job sector. i am from pharma background. will my research and dissertation has bigger impact than my GPA??

Comment: In my graduate program, earning a "C" was cause for dismissal.

Comment: I'm not familiar with *any* industry position that requires an academic transcript, so as long as you get the PhD, you should be fine on that count. (I'm not certain of that, which is why I put this as a comment instead of an answer.)

Comment: This question could have a home on [workplace.se] but we'd need to know the industry/sort of position you're looking at and how the course/PhD is relevant to the job. An academic position could have very different standards from most corporate positions.

Comment: That is to say if you edit your question to include that info we'll be happy to move this question to The Workplace where it can get a workplace related answer rather than an academic's (which doesn't appear to be appropriate in this case)

Comment: What job prospectives? If OP was asking about industry job, I think the question belongs to Workplace SE, or at least between two sites. If it's acamedic job he is looking for, I think it still belongs here.

Comment: As many people have mentioned, a low grade could get you kicked out of the program. If you do make it through though (and I think any departmental advisor would be sympathetic if you had exigent circumstances), then I don't know if anyone would care. I'd like to say that a job that looks at Ph.D GPAs is not a job you want, but that might be a little too extreme.

Comment: If you have a good publication record at the end of the PhD, then one little D won't matter.

Comment: i am on probation right now. Though i aim to maintain A in rest of my course work, but i am bit worried about my professional overview would be. Also if i plan to get away with my master in mid's of my phD will that be a worthy decision.

Comment: Actually, one of my former employers—a very large R&D outfit—had a **strict** GPA cutoff for new hires coming out of both undergraduate and graduate school. So it's not unheard of that a large corporation or other similar entity might care about your "D." However, a smaller company may not show so much concern for this.

Answer (score 9):

Its not the grade that you get that determines gets you the job.  It's your ability to apply what you have learned to new and challenging fields that ultimately determines your qualification for a job.  This is best measured not by grades, but by the quality (and possibly quantity) of publications.   In rare circumstances, as @aeismail suggests, employers look closely at your GPA.  I do not believe this is the norm though.  Most institutions that employ the highly educated look more highly upon strong letters of recommendation and publication history.  As long as you have that, you should not have any problems with this grade on your record.

The ultimate impact of your "D" really depends on the policy of your school.  As @BenNorris indicates, some graduate programs have a minimum performance requirement such that a low grade in a class may impact your retention in your program.  It is best to speak with your advisor, the graduate chair, and possibly even your department chair to discuss the circumstances surrounding your performance, how it will impact your retention, and if there is anything you can do about it.  Immediate dismissal is extremely rare.  Most institutions place the student on probation (and may make you repeat the course in question).

Comment: As a side comment, a friend recently applied for job in management consulting with a top firm, he had to supply a copy of all grades from 9th grade up to and including any grades from grad school plus all external certificates he claimed on his CV. Apparently, within consulting, this is very standard

Answer (score -1):

It depends on where you live. In the US, most tech companies weight GPA low (but still relevant). There's only a soft correlation between GPA and performance. That being said, it doesn't give you an excuse to slack off.

Furthermore, for PhDs most people assume that you have bad grades as you're focusing on research.

With both these facts, I hope you will not worry about it.